# C# add variable in Json string

Tags: c#, json, string, variables

I have some code that I am trying to get more dynamic.

I used a hardcoded ID in my json string to post a new object with NUnit testproject using RestSharp.

But I am now trying to remove the hardcoded object ID and put an empty string variable in my Json string

```cs
string eId;

string tenantAndEntity = "{\"tenant\":\"myTenant\", \"name\":\"myName\","; 

string eIdAndProps = "\"eid\": \"1\", \"props\": {\"MyTestTest\": \"my test\"}}";

string eIdAndPropsPut = "\"eid\": \"1\", \"props\": { \"MyTestTest\": \"my updated test\"}}";

string queryStringBson = "\"queryStringBson\": \"{'eid': '1'}\"}";
```

I tried the $ method and the + eId + method. None of these seem to work.
I wish to replace the "1" with my eId variable

Comment: You create a model, but w/e. string eIdAndProps =$"\"eid\": \"{id}\", \"props\": {{\"MyTestTest\": \"my test\"}}";

Comment: I know this is just test data but really...don't build JSON by hand like that. Make a simple object using anonymous types and serialise it with a proper serialiser. Then there's no mess, no concatenation, no unreadable escaped strings, etc. And when you do that, using variables becomes trivial, as another advantage.

Comment: But re your actual question... `I tried the $ method and the + eId + method`...what **exactly** did you try? And what does "doesn't work" mean exactly? An error in the C#? Or an invalid JSON string? Or what? Because those methods would work, if you use them correctly. We don't know what your problem is because you didn't show your attempt. Therefore we can't tell you what you did wrong or how to fix it (apart from completely changing your approach as I've already mentioned). We can give a ready-made example but that doesn't guarantee you'd understand the difference. Better to see yours first.

Comment: The important bit if you switch to using `$"` is that all non-parameter usage of `{` and `}` has to be doubled up, so the final string should be `string queryStringBson = $"\"queryStringBson\": \"{{'eid': '{id}'}}\"}}";`, this should work. *However*, I urge you to consider using a model class and a json serialization library to produce the Json instead of using string literals, it would be heaps easier to do and much more sane and understandable code for maintenance down the line.

Comment: Also, remember that if you say "I tried something and it didn't work", please post what that *something* was, aka the code you tried, as well as what happened and what you expected to happen. This would make it easier to troubleshoot what you did wrong, beyond just saying "Well, then you did something wrong".

Comment: string queryStringBson = $"\"queryStringBson\": \"{{'eid': '{eId}'}}\"}}"

This is the code I tried. But I get an error saying:
"A field initializer cannot reference the non-static fields, method or property"

Comment: @Joro: That's nothing to do with it being JSON, it's just that you can't initialize one field value using another. Put all of the initialization in your constructor and it will be fine. (If you had provided a [mcve] including the *complete* code rather than just statements which could have been anywhere, and included the error message as well, we could have explained that a lot earlier.)

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, try to not build json in raw strings if you are not experienced with it. Anyways, it is a matter of correct quotations:

```
int eid = 1;

string tenantAndEntity = "{\"tenant\":\"myTenant\", \"name\":\"myName\","; 
string eIdAndProps = "\"eid\": \"" + eid + "\", \"props\": {\"MyTestTest\": \"my test\"}}";
string eIdAndPropsPut = "\"eid\": \"" + eid + "\", \"props\": { \"MyTestTest\": \"my updated test\"}}";
string queryStringBson = "\"queryStringBson\": \"{'eid': '" + eid + "'}\"}";
```

Comment: " try to not build json in raw strings if you are not experienced with it"...personally I'd change that to simply "don't ever build json in raw strings" :-). But yes I agree with the sentiment.

Comment: Building raw json strings is faster then serializing objects, so if you really need to squeeze performance out of something specific, then it could be a way to go. Personally I would never recommend it unless in extreme perf corner cases.

Comment: Absolutely. And this is just a test script, as the OP mentioned, so it's probably not that kind of situation.